# Conductivity vs Attenuation

Tags: conductivity

Attenuation of em waves, when they travel over a surface, happens because the em waves induce a current in the surface and loose energy. EM waves travel farther over sea/ocean. Conductivity of sea/ocean is high. Please explain the connection between high conductivity and longer ranges.

Comment: homework? guess in this form its of topic...

Comment: Which do you think would work better, a waveguide made out of metal, or waveguide made out of partially conductive carbon-loaded plastic?  Why?

Comment: Perhaps consider the impedance of air is lower when moist Dk=60 in moisture with salinity reduces path loss vs a vacuum but causes dispersion in microwave > tbd GHz due to wavelengths are smaller. VLF is global due to Van Allen reflections and this changes with sunset/rise diurnal effects. VHF is excellent for moon bouncing to 5 continents and my ex-colleague did this in mid-70’s. voices travel further over water also due to curvature of pressure waves towards water, so diffraction of lens effect works on some wavelengths